# Performance of joblib Parallel loop with numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I'm doing some statistical computations in python using numpy. My current implementation is not parallelized so far. So I was looking into python joblib Parallel for a simple loop-parallelization.

My non-parallelized part of the code looks like this:

```
def calcRADMatInt( i, j , RADMat, pdfMu, pdfSigma):
  if i==j:
    RADMat[i, j] = 0.0
  else:
    RADMat[i, j] = calcRAD( pdfMu[i], np.squeeze( pdfSigma[i]), pdfMu[j], np.squeeze( pdfSigma[j]) )
    RADMat[j, i] = RADMat[i,j]

def caldRADMat(....):

....
....
  RADMat = np.zeros( (numLandmark, numLandmark) )

  for i in range( 0, numLandmark):
    for j in range( i, numLandmark)):
      calcRADMatInt( i, j, RADMat, pdfMu, pdfSigma)

....
....
```

I've tried to parallelize it like this:

```
def caldRADMat(....):
....
....

  RADMat = np.zeros( (numLandmark, numLandmark) )

  for i in range( 0, numLandmark):
    Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(calcRADMatInt)( i, j, RADMat, pdfMu, pdfSigma) for j in    range( i, numLandmark))

....
....
```

However, the resulting parallel code runs significantly slower than the non-parallelized version.

So I guess my actual questions are:
Am I using joblib Parallel correctly?
Is this the right way to parallelize computation of numpy ndarray elements?

Comment: Numpy is faster than a loop. Maybe you could modify the `calcRAD` method to work directly on numpy arrays.

Comment: I don't know much about `joblib`, but I would be surprised if `RADMat` is anything other than an array of zeros at the end of your parallel loop (not only is it slower, but it's possibly incorrect too ;).

Comment: yes, there is indeed a bug. it was commited during rewriting for parallelization. thanks for the hint. I guess I should go with numpy arrays instead of nested for loops then. thanks for your comment @eumiro.

Comment: @tisch If this question is no longer valid, you should mark it closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could include both for loops in the Parallel task, as follows:

```
def calcRADMatInt( i, j , RADMat, pdfMu, pdfSigma):
  if i==j:
    RADMat[i, j] = 0.0
  else:
    RADMat[i, j] = calcRAD( pdfMu[i], np.squeeze( pdfSigma[i]), pdfMu[j], np.squeeze( pdfSigma[j]) )
    RADMat[j, i] = RADMat[i,j]

def caldRADMat(....):
....
....

  RADMat = np.zeros( (numLandmark, numLandmark) )

  Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(calcRADMatInt)
  (i, j, RADMat, pdfMu, pdfSigma)
  for i in range(0,numLandmark)
  for j in range( i, numLandmark))

....
....
```

If you call the Parallel task inside a loop, as you did it, your computation is sub-optimal.

Hope it helps!

Best regards,